# Set minimum height for cells in RTF document?

Tags: file-io, cell, rtf

I'm writing a program that programatically creates (without the use of an external library) an rtf document that has a simple table in it.  Here is the relevant rtf code:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd\trgaph144
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx1000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx2000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx3000
cell 1\intbl\cell
lots of text in cell two\intbl\cell
cell 3\intbl\cell
\row
}
```

The issue is that this code will make the cells as short (height-wise) as possible while still holding their contents.  **I would like the cells to have a minimum height (say 50 units), and have them expand if their contents exceeds their capacity.  How can I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...All you have to do is add "\trrhN" where N is the min height for the row...For more details check out: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm